# Why does 0L not equal 0 when cast to an object?

Tags: c#

I don't think I understand why the first statement evaluates to `true` and the last statement evaluates to `false`, but it's been a long day.

Can somebody explain it?

```
0L.Equals(0) // true
((object)0L).Equals(0L) // true
((object)0L).Equals(0) // false
```

Comment: I think the real issue is which "0" is being created, and your casting is making the compiler chose different variations each time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Object.Equals` first compares the types if the object is a value type which it is. Both are different in this case.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If the current instance is a value type, the Equals(Object) method
>   tests for value equality. Value equality means the following: The two
>   objects are of the same type. As the following example shows, a Byte
>   object that has a value of 12 does not equal an Int32 object that has
>   a value of 12, because the two objects have different run-time types.

Comment: In order to understand why this is the case though, one needs to understand the boxing that is going on. Structs don't have inheritance like reference types: `object` is not the base class in the same sense that it is for reference types -- casting a value-type to `object` actually wraps the value inside of an `object` instance. For a reference type the overridden `Equals` of `Int64` would have been called even if you cast the instance to `object`.

Comment: Ok, the boxed Int64 object doesn't use the Equals method of Int64 directly. My opinion is that it'd be nicer if it did, but I get why it can't.

Comment: @ken: value types are not reference types even if they are boxed. As an aside: they behave like if they were when you compare them with `==` instead of `Equals` and return `false` even if the value seems to be equal: `((object)0L) == ((object)0L) // false`. That's because the boxing creates new objects and `==` compares reference equality.

Answer (score 0):

```
((object)0L).Equals(0)
```

here you are comparing a type of object to a type of int(dont quote me on int it may be another numeric type)

the types are different.

Comment: Not that I disagree with your reasoning, but why would that be different than the first example?

Comment: The `L` means it's a `long (Int64)` or `ulong` (depending on size).

Comment: @tim what type does 0 take?

Comment: @Buck3y3 - Not sure what you mean.  `0L` is a literal integer of type `long`. See [long (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) - check out the Literals section.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET two objects of numeric type will evaluate as equal no matter the kind of numeric type (for the most part exceptions are there) where here you are comparing a type of `object` to a numeric type(int32 I think but am not sure)

Comment: @Buck3y3 No; that's not the case at all, as is evidenced clearly by the code in this question.

Comment: @Tim I understand that half but what about `0` in `.Equals(0)`.  Is the `0` of type int32?  or does it take a different type?

Comment: @Buck3y3 - Ah.  That I'm not sure of.  I would venture a guess that `Int32` would be the default, but that may depend on a number of factors.

Comment: @Servy I worded my answer and comments incorrectly.  When casting to object you are calling a different .equals

Comment: @Buck3y3 Yes, that's true, and since that is happening, clearly numeric types are not evaluated regardless of their type.  If you're not using the `object.Equals` methods, and are instead using comparison operations that are more strongly typed, then it's not *possible* to compare two different values of different types.  There is no `Equals(int a, long b)` overload, or any sort of `INumeric` interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
0L.Equals(0) // true
```

This resolves to the `long.Equals` method, which accepts a `long` as a parameter.  The actual expression provided for the parameter to an `int`.  That `int` is implicitly converted to a `long`, so the `long` `0` is passed in, which is equal to the other value.

```
((object)0L).Equals(0L) // true
((object)0L).Equals(0) // false
```

Boxing the `long` here prevents the use of the `long.Equals` overload, and leaves only the `object.Equals` overload, which accepts an `object` parameter.  Since the parameter is `object` both snippets, each having a `long` and an `int` respectively, both get boxed.  The `object.Equals` implementation also checks the type of the parameter and considers any objects that are of different types to be not equal.  The first of these two snippets passes the check, at which point it goes on to check the values, finding them equal.  The second snippet fails the check, resulting in a `false`.